# Failed to deploy Cloud Data Fusion "Transfer Data From MySQL to Google BigQuery" template pipeline

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I've just tried Cloud Data Fusion, `Transfer Data From MySQL to Google BigQuery` template pipeline. After the configuration of the setting, I got the error below while deploying the pipeline. Any advice?

```
Plugin named 'BigQueryTable' of type 'batchsink' not found.
```

## How to re-produce the problem?

1. Choose `Transfer Data From MySQL to Google BigQuery` pipeline from Cloud Data Fusion Hub, and a new pipeline will be created.
2. Configure some settings in a MySQL node (caution: BigQuery node cannot be modified).
3. Click [Deploy] button.
4. The error below will be shown:

```
Plugin named 'BigQueryTable' of type 'batchsink' not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with that particular template.
I've fixed the issue in this [pull request](https://github.com/cdapio/hub/pull/310), and updated the Hub.
I verified that I was able to modify the BigQuery node and deploy the pipeline.

Let me know if you have any further issues.